# What to do if a library you want to use doesn't support Carthage yet

Tags: ios, carthage

I'm in the middle of assessing whether Carthage would be a good fit for my project and one of the questions I want to find out answers for is what to do when a library/framework I want to use doesn't have support for Carthage yet.

Have any of you had this issue and found a solution for it before?

Thanks

Comment: Well , you can mail em to support the Carthage and wait,or you can write one of your own ,given you have the codebase from GitHub provided you are not breaching any conduct related issue  .

Comment: Use Cocoapods if the library supports or import it manually in your project.

Comment: We decided not to use cocoapods for various reasons, and manual import doesnt sound like a good idea to me, not for the long term

Comment: Why do you think manual import is not a good idea? That is the official Apple's way to use libraries (because there is no other better one, besides swift package manager). My suggestion is to add library's project as git submodule and include it's Xcode project as subproject and it should work automatically (usually)

Comment: To get into the whole manual import vs dependency management would be a different conversation altogether which I don't want to get into

Answer (score 3):

The main thing that Carthage needs is a Framework and for that Framework's scheme to be a ["shared"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH9-SW3) scheme.

So one way to get a project to support Carthage is to fork it on GitHub and then share the scheme in Xcode and check that into your fork, then use that fork's address in your Cartfile. If you're successful at this then maybe do a Pull Request with the author of the original so your Carthage support can be grafted back into the main repository.

If the project you're wanting to use doesn't use a Framework, then you have some more work to do since the project will need refactoring but it's possible. Here's an old [PDF viewer project](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) and the Carthage support someone [grafted into a fork](https://github.com/mozinator/Reader) by refactoring things into a Framework (there was some reason it wasn't accepted as a PR and now the main repo is deprecated but it'll give you some idea of what's expected)